# Not able to set the variable correctly in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am reading a values from the xml file using batch ,
values are like Age="18" 
When the value is extracted i don't want the double quotes

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b in ('type <file_name> ^| FIND "info" ) do (
echo %%b
set string =%%b
```

string = Age="18" ( getting error here)

in the info tag
`<info Name="xxx" Age="18"></info>`

i need only the value 18 to be stored in a variable

Need assistance

Comment: Do not add spaces around equal signs. `set string=%%b`

Comment: I would advise that you use a scripting language that can read and write xml with a native method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of choosing the `2`nd token with   as the delimiter, you probably want the `4`th token using the `"` as a delimiter:

```bat
 @For /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir%find.exe" /I "<info "^<"filename.txt"^"') Do @Set "age=%%G"
```

You may also wish, for robustness, to match a more unique pattern. You can do that by choosing `findstr.exe` instead of `find.exe`:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir%findstr.exe" /IR "<info\ Name=\"[a-Z]*\"\ Age=\"[0-9]*\">" "filename.txt"^"') Do @Set "age=%%G"
```

---

Please note that the pattern I have used for the age, allows for superscript digits. *However, this scenario is unlikely ever to be encountered, in your actual case, so I figured that this pattern should suffice.*

Comment: Thanks got an idea.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done with:

```
for /F "tokens=5 delims==> " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"<info .* Age=\"[0123456789][0123456789]*\"" "XmlFile.xml"') do echo %%~I& set "string=%%~I"
```

**FOR** executes in this case in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as additional arguments. So executed is in background with Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"<info .* Age=\"[0123456789][0123456789]*\"" "XmlFile.xml"
```

**FINDSTR** runs a case-sensitive regular expression search for a line containing `<info` containing the attribute `Age` and the attribute value being a number. The found line is output to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of the background command process captured by **FOR**.

After started `cmd.exe` closed itself after `findstr.exe` terminated, **FOR** processes the captured output line by line with skipping empty lines.

The line is split up into substrings using `=` and `>` and space as string delimiters because of `delims==>` . The fifth substring is the value of attribute `Age` enclosed in double quotes which is assigned to the specified loop variable `I` because of `tokens=5`. The double quotes are removed because of using modifier `%~I`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`